# Home intrusion detection system - UltraSync 1347 - reliability

Tags: security, home-security

Does anyone have information about UltraSync 1347, a system that allows you to control a home intrusion system remotely from your smartphone (receive alerts, arm or disarm the system)?

I [could not](https://www.google.com/search?q=ultrasync%201374) find much info beyond a [PDF brochure](https://www.utcfssecurityproducts.eu/intrusion/brochures/1374_UltraSync_Professional_Brochure_EN.pdf). At the end of the brochure, there is mention of [UTC Fire & Security](https://www.google.com/search?q=UTC%20Fire%20%26%20Security). Google returns a frame with the company details: UTC Climate, Controls & Security, 16.7 billion USD revenue.

Looks legit so far. I didn't find any horror stories, or vulnerabilities. But I didn't find any track record either, or even datasheet or whitepaper.

I'm concerned about:

- Hardware reliability
- Software future compatibility (how long will the app be supported on Android/iOS
- Software reliability (is it already working correctly on Android 8.1.0 and iOS)
- Overall security. **Could someone take control of the system remotely?**